# How can I use variable from a private method in another private method ? C# ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, methods, private

So I've got a class with private method and I want to use a variable from one method to another one.
I don't know how and where to start.
Should I use get and set or a creat a full public method, I don't know.

Here is the first method and I want to use the variable "prixTotal"

```
private string RecupPrixTransaction(XmlDocument doc)
{
    XmlNodeList nl = null;
    XmlNode nodeDevise = null;
    string data = string.Empty;
    string devise = string.Empty;
    decimal acompteTotal = 0;
    decimal prixTotal = 0;

    if (doc == null)
        return (data);
    nodeDevise = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Caddie/GroupesProduits/GroupeProduit[@IdGroupe='" + this.guid + "']/Devise");
    if (nodeDevise == null)
        return (data);
    devise = nodeDevise.InnerText;
    nl = doc.SelectNodes("/Caddie/GroupesProduits/GroupeProduit[@IdGroupe='" + this.guid + "']/Produits/Produit");
    if (nl == null)
        return (data);
    try
    {
        foreach (XmlNode nd in nl)
        {
            prixTotal += decimal.Parse(nd["PrixTotal"].InnerText, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            acompteTotal += decimal.Parse(nd["AcompteTotal"].InnerText, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
        data += "Prix total de la transaction: <strong>" + prixTotal + "</strong> " + devise + "<br />";
        data += "Acompte total payé: <strong>" + acompteTotal + "</strong> " + devise + "<br />";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        data += "Prix/acompte invalide.<br />";
    }
    return (data);
}
```

And here it's the method where I want to use the variable "prixTotal"

```
private void AffTransa(string id, SqlConnection sqlConnect)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    decimal recapPrixTotal = RecupPrixTransaction(prixTotal);


    reader = Database.ExecuteReader(EnumConstant.SqlLecture + "SELECT * FROM transactionfin WHERE IdTransactionFin='" + id + "'", sqlConnect);
    if (reader.Read())
    {

        this.lTransa.Text = "<h2>Détail de la transaction " + id + "</h2><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "Date de la transaction: <b>" + reader["TransactionFinDate"] + "</b><br />";
        this.date = reader["TransactionFinDate"].ToString();
        this.lTransa.Text += "Solution de paiement: <b>" + MyRegex.ReplacePaiementSol(reader["PaiementSolution_IdPaiementSolution"].ToString()) + "</b><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "{[{-}]}Mode: <b>" + MyRegex.ReplaceMode(reader["TransactionFinMode"].ToString()) + "</b><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "Etat: <b>" + MyRegex.ReplaceEtat(reader["TransactionFinEtat"].ToString()) + "</b><br />";
        if (reader["TransactionFinUrlRetour"].ToString() != "&nbsp;")
            this.lTransa.Text += "Url de retour: <a href=\"" + reader["TransactionFinUrlRetour"].ToString() + "\">" + MyRegex.ReplaceUrlRetour(reader["TransactionFinUrlRetour"].ToString()) + "</a><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "<br /><br />Id Transaction: <b>" + reader["TransactionFinIdTransaction"] + "</b><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "Guid: <b>" + reader["TransactionFinGuidGroupe"].ToString() + "</b><br />";
        this.guid = reader["TransactionFinGuidGroupe"].ToString();
        this.lTransa.Text += "Id action contact: <b>" + reader["ActionContact_IdActionContact"] + "</b><br />";
        this.lTransa.Text += "Id vente entete: <b>" + reader["VenteEntete_IdVenteEntete"] + "</b><br />";
        if (reader["TransactionFinDetail"] != null && reader["TransactionFinDetail"].ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            this.tbTransa.Visible = true;
            this.tbTransa.Text = XmlParsing.IndentXml(reader["TransactionFinDetail"].ToString()); 
            this.lRecap.Text += "Recapitulatif de la Transaction : " ;
            this.recapTransa.Visible = true;
            this.recapTransa.Text += "#Fournisseur" + "\n" +
                                     "#Internaute" + "\n" +
                                     "#Montants" + "\n" + recapPrixTotal +
                                     "#Produits" + "\n" +
                                     "#Suppléments" + "\n";

        }

    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

I tried to call the method like this but this doesn't work

```
decimal recapPrixTotal = RecupPrixTransaction(prixTotal);
```

EDIT :

At the top of the class i've put the variable "prixTotal" like this

```
  public partial class SeeDetail : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private decimal prixTotal = 0; 
    ...
}
```

I've removed it from the method RecupPrixTransaction
Andin the AffTransa method, i call it like this

```
decimal recapPrixTotal = prixTotal;
```

In the method RecupPrixTransaction the result of "prixTotal" is the good one 
But in the AffTransa method the number is always 0

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: What is `prixTotal`? Is it an `XmlDocument ` because that's what it's expecting

Comment: Are those two methods in the same class?

Comment: prixTotal came from an XML yes

Comment: Yes both methods are in the same class

Comment: Say when you call this methods.

Comment: @Mathias , you can use a auto implemented property to solve this, check my post below

Comment: Thanks for all your answers ! I'm about to try it :)

Comment: @Mathias, sure, you can let me know here how it goes, or if you need more help, I'd be happy to look at it

Comment: @Mathias hi Mathias, just following up to see if it has worked for you, if you need more help please feel free to reach out. And if the post has answered your question can you mark as resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

In this way its, impossible. Now `prixTotal` is in method scope and its inaccessible from outside. But you can move `decimal prixTotal = 0;` to class scope and then this variable will be accessible from both methods.

```
Class A
{
    private decimal prixTotal = 0;

    private void Method A ....
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and at the end it always return 0. I need the value from prixTotal in RecupPrixTransaction to the other method

Comment: I don't see how OP's code would even run when he is expecting a decimal back but us returning a string `data` which to me looks like html

Comment: @Mathias show how you call this 2 methods. On the same instance of class? Each new instance has at the begining of life `prixTotal = 0`

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to call the method like this but this doesn't work
>   decimal recapPrixTotal = RecupPrixTransaction(prixTotal);

- The return type of `RecupPrixTransaction` is of type `String`
- The parameters accepted by `RecupPrixTransaction` is of type `XmlDocument` and not `decimal`

*To Solve:*

- Declare `private decimal prixTotal { get; set; }` at *Class* scope
- ```
  private string RecupPrixTransaction(XmlDocument doc)
  {
  prixTotal =0;
  ...
  }
  ```
- ```
  private void AffTransa(string id, SqlConnection sqlConnect)
  {
  decimal recapPrixTotal= prixTotal;
  ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way this will work.

You are calling

```
private string RecupPrixTransaction(XmlDocument doc)
```

which to me suggests the method is returning a string and passing a `XmlDocument`

but what you are passing is

```
decimal recapPrixTotal = RecupPrixTransaction(prixTotal);
```

Where it looks like you are wanting a `decimal` and passing an (to us at least) variable called `prixTotal`

If you want it to return a `decimal`, I suggest changing the return type of the method, assuming that you ARE passing it an `XmlDocument`.

If they are in the same class, I don't see why the above would not hit the method.